# Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml - Again

Tags: vb.net, closedxml

It seems that this problem is a very popular one, and I've already read nearly a dozen of similar questions, but all offer the same solution (install and reference DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5), which I already did, and it's still not working.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, referencing ClosedXML version 0.93 and it's dependency DocumentFormat.OpenXML version 2.5 in my project. Both .dll files are stored next to .exe file of my project. Visual Studio appears to see these references:

[image]

At the top of my code, I also have:

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports ClosedXML
```

However, when I call a simple test code,

```
Dim workbook = New ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook()
Dim worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet")
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!"
workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx")
```

I get an error, saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.7.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=8fb06cb64d019a17' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm at loss as to why this error occurs. If I write DocumentFormat.OpenXml. in my code, I get a list of suggested functions in that library, so the references must be loaded properly.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe the solution you tried but did not work? That would avoid someone wasting time posting the same solution again.

Comment: My last paragraph was about that solution. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that, my mistake.

Comment: Use NuGet to manage your libraries. It will sort out problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you noted that in the screen shot you're using version 2.5 in the references for the OpenXml assembly, but the exception message is referencing the newer 2.7.2?  That could be your issue.  It could be that you've referenced 2.5, but the "ClosedXML" is expecting 2.7.2 and when it doesn't find it tosses an error?

I would get 2.7.2, update your reference and then see if that works.

Comment: (+1) yes that's it, clash of versions, incompatibity issue between the loaded assembly and one that is declared.

Comment: Correct. ClosedXML 0.93 requires OpenXML 2.7.2 or higher. Using NuGet should solve these problems.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to nugget and update the document xml reference to the latest one which is 2.7 and the issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

add document.openxml dll refernce into your project, you can get this dll through nuget package manager(please install required version of dll)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).